# How do you pass webgl functions as variables

Tags: javascript, webgl

I could not figure out how to do this. I keep getting an illegal invocation. 
Let's say that from a function in my program I call a function ...

```
setGlState( cGl.DEPTH_WRITEMASK, true, cGl.depthMask );
```

So I'm passing different states and functions to the setGlState function so that it can make some decisions and call the gl function if it needs to set state.

```
setGlState = function ( cap, value, setterFunc ) {
    ....

    if( needsToBeSent ) {
        setterFunc( value ) 
    }
}
```

For some reason this code does not work. Do I need to bind the function or call the function? Is it a problem that the function is on the gl context. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a new function that will call the old function in the right context (so `this` is `cGl` inside the function).

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) will do that for you.

```
setGlState( cGl.DEPTH_WRITEMASK.bind(cGl), true, cGl.depthMask.bind(cGl) );
```

The documentation linked to above includes a shim for browsers that do not natively support `bind`.

Comment: Uggghh. Thank you. It wasn't working still and I found a problem somewhere else that, after correcting, made it work. I appreciate it.